# Get address from Geocode latitude and longitude

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, geocoding, google-geocoder

For the bulk of my application, I am getting the latitude, longitude, postal code, etc of a town/city from Geocoder.  I am just putting in the city and state and in return I am getting

I am in a scenario where I have a venue.  That venue needs an address and I am getting that venues latitude and longitude from another source.  Using the Geocoder gem, am I able to get an address by giving it a latitude and longitude?

Comment: yes, you can get do it: http://www.rubygeocoder.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `reverse_geocode_by`. It's all in here: https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder

Comment: how can we do it in rails console ? something like reverse_geocode_by(lat, long) ?

Comment: @Reality did you find out how to do it from the console?

Answer (score 16):

Run in `Rails console`.

```
latitude = 40.0397
longitude = -76.30144
geo_localization = "#{latitude},#{longitude}"
query = Geocoder.search(geo_localization).first
query.address
```

Answer (score 3):

If i am not wrong you want to get the address from latitude and longitude, and this can be done using [RubyGeocoder](http://www.rubygeocoder.com/) .

Look in to Simple Reverse Geocoding by Coordinates which says :

Given a Place model with known latitude/longitude coordinates, automatically fetch address and store in location attribute (stored in address attribute if :address option omitted):

```
# app/models/place.rb

reverse_geocoded_by :latitude, :longitude, address: :location
after_validation :reverse_geocode
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're not looking to integrate with a model:

```
lat = 40.0397
lon = -76.30144
query = "#{lat},#{lon}"
first_result = Geocoder.search(query).first
if first_result.present?
  puts first_result.city
end
```