# How to get city name using latitude and longitude on controller in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am trying to get city name of current user in user controller method.here i am getting lat long of user current location.

Comment: Possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20827675/get-address-from-geocode-latitude-and-longitude

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get address from Geocode latitude and longitude](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20827675/get-address-from-geocode-latitude-and-longitude)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Geocoder` for find city name using `lat` and `lon` 
https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder

Following is sample code

```
lat = "latitude"
lon = "longitude"
lat_lon = "#{lat},#{lon}"
response = Geocoder.search(lat_lon).first
puts response.city if response.present?
```